# Can I get my rank on SO according to the year I joined?

Tags: discussion

I know how I can see my overall rank. But I find it is an injustice to compare myself with those who joined SO 4 to 5 years ago. 
So I want to know my rank by comparing with only those who joined SO in same year when I joined (only rating after this year should be counted). Is there any way to find out or do I have to tolerate this injustice?

Comment: Anything's possible with [SEDE](http://data.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: @Robert, blatant lies. SEDE cannot possibly make me outrank Jon Skeet.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi I am sure you can find something.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi: [Lies!](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/204717/beat-the-skeet)

Comment: @Jeroen, this violates [the book](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9134/jon-skeet-facts). Something *might* happen.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Been wanting to create an interesting query in SEDE, so I went ahead and created one [here](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/168186/what-is-my-reputation-rank-among-accounts-created-in-the-same-year) for this.

```
DECLARE @UserId INT = ##UserId##
DECLARE @Reputation INT
DECLARE @StartTime DATETIME

SELECT @Reputation = Reputation, @StartTime = CreationDate FROM Users 
WHERE Id = @UserID

SELECT 1 + COUNT(Id) AS Rank FROM Users WHERE Reputation > @Reputation 
AND DATEDIFF(YEAR, @StartTime, CreationDate) = 0
```

Testing it out, it gives me 12533 for you, so it seems you are ranked #12533 (and most likely in a tie).

---

By request in the comments, I made a separate query that gives you your rank [as a percentile](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/202551/what-is-my-reputation-percentile-among-accounts-created-in-the-same-year)

```
DECLARE @UserId INT = ##UserId##
DECLARE @Reputation INT
DECLARE @Rank INT
DECLARE @Total INT
DECLARE @StartTime DATETIME

SELECT @Reputation = Reputation, @StartTime = CreationDate FROM Users 
WHERE Id = @UserID

SELECT @Rank = COUNT(Id) FROM Users WHERE Reputation < @Reputation 
AND DATEDIFF(YEAR, @StartTime, CreationDate) = 0

SELECT @Total = COUNT(Id) FROM Users 
WHERE DATEDIFF(YEAR, @StartTime, CreationDate) = 0

SELECT (@Rank * 100.0)/@Total
```

That gives me ~98.89 for you (in other words, you have more rep than 98.89% of users created in the same year as you).

However, if I tweak this slightly to [ignore users with 1 rep](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/205075/what-is-my-reputation-percentile-among-accounts-created-in-the-same-year-ignore), it drops to around ~96.2.

More seasoned Stack Overflow users may be more interested in the percentile when [ignoring all users with less than 200 reputation](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/205076/what-is-my-reputation-percentile-among-accounts-created-in-the-same-year-ignore), since that's the threshold to be shown in the reputation leagues. This drops you down all the way to 21.47, but it *did* ignore a lot of the users below you.

---

If you don't know what your user ID is, go to your Stack Overflow profile and look at the URL; it's the number before your display name. Using my profile URL as an example

```
http://stackoverflow.com/users/1476062/dennis-meng
                               ^^^^^^^
```

my ID would be 1476062.

Comment: Nice. Since I don't speak SQL: I figure putting "MONTH" or "DAY" on the last line instead of "YEAR" will do the expected thing? For example with "DAY", it would show my rank compared to everybody who joined on the same day or later? I like the result if that's the case.

Comment: @RetoKoradi Not quite; if you only changed "YEAR" to "DAY" you get rank among those who joined on the same day, not same day or later. If you wanted same day or later, you'd also have to change the equals sign to a `>=` or `<=` (I *think* `<=`, but I'd have to play around a bit to be sure)

Comment: Ah, yes, that makes sense now that I look at the expression more closely. It's probably `>=` for this purpose, based on my experiments.

Comment: It wouldn't be too hard to check, just change `1 + COUNT(Id)` to `CreationDate` and compare. (For what it's worth, I'm not really much of a SQL guy either; I know enough to play around but can't do anything close to fancy)

Comment: I also don't know SQL, but if you're looking for improvements, I'd love to see a percentage rank, too!

Comment: @user1118321 Yeah, I can do that. I'll post a link when I get to it.

Comment: Always wanted this. Feeling good as I rank 55 :)

Comment: I'm 1338. Missed 1337 by one!

Comment: @AmitJoki You might be interested in [the list of users above you](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/205020/).

Comment: @svick good! But something is missing as the rank 1 holder had his account created 1 yr, 3 months before and mine was created 7 months before

Comment: @AmitJoki Both of those dates are in 2013, so I don't see the problem.

Comment: @svick but I think, in 8 months, I could've got a higher rank. Would be good if it was based on months instead of years.

Comment: Are you sure this is right?  It gave me 151.  I don't know whether to be proud or terrified

Comment: @GabeSechan Well, given that you shoot up pretty fast and SEDE doesn't update very often (I think daily), I'd actually say that's a little low for you. I tried checking numbers with other queries; it's in the right ballpark, but getting an exact read on a fast moving target is hard :).

Comment: @user1118321 There, added percentile as well. Enjoy! :)